# Alternative to Multicast

Tags: java, networking, tcp, udp

I am trying to implement an application where a part of it functions similar to chat. There are several users and the connection is P2P. The data send from each peer to the others should be  serialised objects. I am having difficulty deciding how the data will be send. The best choice seemed Multicast , but since its chat i can't afford losing data(that would corrupt the text ??). On the other hand if I use TCP , each peer should be connected to every other peer in order to listen for updates and that sounds wrong (??)/would create a mess.

I would like suggestions as to how I could implement something like that(send data to multiple clients,listen for updates without centralized server).I have already checked JXTA and I am trying to see if its possible to implement this on my own.Also i have read about reliable UDP but haven't found any 'official' solutions/something i could use easily.

p.s I have seen similar questions to this one and was hoping for a more personalised help.

Comment: JGroups API can be used here. http://www.jgroups.org/

Comment: I see a lot of talk about NAT and how that causes problems with P2P applications . Do you know in which scenarios /how likely it is to have that problem with jgroups  ?

Comment: I have primarily worked with JGroups API over a LAN since group based multicast addressing is best within a close network. In WAN multicasting based communication poses problems. I believe JGroups has solutions if multicasting in WAN is required (such as over internet).

Comment: what about when the devices are using wifi, but not connected to any network and they want to communicate each other just like bluetooth (but please don't use bluetooth) ? Is it possible to implement it by jgroups for wifi communication and connection? @UsmanSaleem,

Comment: I believe that JGroups is only usable after you establish a connection between the devices. Establishing the connection should not be a concern for that library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org/).